# Unable to perform sum operation in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to perform sum operation on my data in pig but it is not accepting explicit type casting i have tried replacing (int) with double while performing sum.

Code

```
drivers = LOAD '/sachin/drivers.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
time = LOAD '/sachin/timesheet.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
drivdata = FILTER drivers BY $0>1;
timedata = filter time by $0>0;
drivgrp = group timedata by $0;
drivinfo = foreach drivgrp generate group as id , SUM(timedata.$2) as totalhr , SUM(timedata.$3) as totmillogged;
drivfinal = foreach drivdata generate $0 as id , $1 as name;
result = join drivfinal by id , drivinfo by id;
finalres = foreach result generate $0 as id, $1 as name, $3 as hrslogged, $4 as mileslogged;
summile = foreach finalres generate (int)SUM(mileslogged);
DUMP summile;
```

Error Message

```
grunt> exec /home/sachin/sec.pig
2017-12-13 21:57:58,812 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 1 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:58,854 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:58,996 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:59,036 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:59,080 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:59,121 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:59,192 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_INT 2 time(s).
2017-12-13 21:57:59,246 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: <line 10, column 41> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
Details at logfile: /home/sachin/pig_1513175202309.log
grunt>
```

I am actually trying to perform operation for each driver in the top 5 list and finding the miles logged and the percentage of mileslogged by the driver over the total miles logged and store the result in hdfs.

Link for Dataset:`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hortonworks/data-tutorials/master/tutorials/hdp/how-to-process-data-with-apache-pig/assets/driver_data.zip`

Can anyone help me to solve this problem or help me to understand what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast mileslogged and then call the SUM function

```
finalres = foreach result generate $0 as id, $1 as name, $3 as hrslogged, (int)$4 as mileslogged; 
summile = foreach finalres generate SUM(mileslogged);
```

Also I noticed that you are not specifying the datatype in the load statement.The default datatype is bytearray and I suspect you will get the correct result if you don't explicitly cast the fields in the subsequent steps.

Comment: It is still giving me error   ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: <line 10, column 36> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: Try casting before the SUM function step.finalres = foreach result generate $0 as id, $1 as name, $3 as hrslogged, (int)$4 as mileslogged; and just call the sum function summile = foreach finalres generate SUM(mileslogged);

Comment: Sample Data is given in the link above in decription

Comment: (11,Jamie Engesser,3642.0,179300.0)
(10,George Vetticaden,3232.0,147150.0)
(33,Sridhara Sabbella,2759.0,139285.0)
(25,Jean-Philippe Playe,2723.0,139180.0)
(39,David Kaiser,2745.0,138788.0
                                                                                                               This is ordered output but the last column should display percentage instead of the mileslogged.

Comment: Seems like the error disappeared and now the output is incorrect?

Comment: no this is order by output i am posting here ,it is still giving me error

Answer (score 0):

From 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#sum
SUM is defined as

> Computes the sum of the numeric values in a single-column bag. SUM requires a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global sums and a GROUP BY statement for group sums.

You code is passing a double whereas SUM requires a BAG containing doubles. No need to typecast but you need to group before calling the SUM function.

```
allres = group finalres ALL;
summile = foreach allres generate SUM(finalres.mileslogged);
DUMP summile;
```